# Как работать на сайте

Tags: веб-программирование

У меня есть свой сайт (от megagroup.ru) Хочу писать статьи. Как научиться пользоваться всеми возможностями сайта?? изображения, активные ссылки и.т.д Можете поделиться где я могу найти книгу, статью??

Comment: Если поискать в гугле, то можно найти [документацию](http://help.megagroup.ru/).

Comment: Обратитесь за поддержкой к тем, кто вам этот сайт предоставил.